# split a column into multiple columns by delimiter in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I have a data that looks like this:

| V1 | J123 |
| --- | --- |
| 112233 | c("1990-03-29","2008-01-15","1986-07-28") |

I would like to separate the column with the dates into separate columns according to ",". Something like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | 1990-03-29 | 2008-01-15 | 1986-07-28 |

I tried

```
test <- data %>% separate(sep = ",")
```

this doesnt seem to separate all the dates but only the first one. Could you please help me out

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The format of J123 looks like the syntax of R. Maybe you want to handle it with ease in the step before?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(col = J123,
          into = paste0("V", 1:3),
          regex = '"([0-9-]+)","([0-9-]+)","([0-9-]+)"') %>%
  cbind(df$V1, .)
   df$V1         V1         V2         V3
1 112233 1990-03-29 2008-01-15 1986-07-28
```

Alternatively use `separate`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(J123= str_remove(J123, "[c)(]")) %>% 
  separate(J123, 
           into = paste0("V", 1:3),
           sep = ",")
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly let me know if this is what you were anticipating.

```
df %>% 
  unnest(J123) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(key = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key, J123)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `tidyr::separate` just as you did:

### Data:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 112233,
                 J123 = 'c("1990-03-29","2008-01-15","1986-07-28")')

      V1                                     J123
1 112233 c("1990-03-29","2008-01-15","1986-07-28")
```

### Code:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(J123= str_remove(J123, "c")) %>% 
  mutate(J123= str_remove(J123, "\\(")) %>% 
  mutate(J123= str_remove(J123, "\\)")) %>% 
  mutate(J123= str_remove_all(J123, '\\"')) %>% 
tidyr::separate(J123, sep = ",", into = c("V2","V3","V4"))
```

### Output:

```
      V1         V2         V3         V4
1 112233 1990-03-29 2008-01-15 1986-07-28
```